# Does spectral decomposition exist for non-self-adjoint operators?

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

In theory, if a linear operator $P$ in a Hilbert space $H$ is self-adjoint, we can decompose it as $Pu=\sum_i \lambda_i <\phi_i,u>\phi_i$, where $\phi_i$ is the eigenfunction of $P$. And we can further obtain that $P^ku=\sum_i \lambda_i^k <\phi_i,u>\phi_i$. It is important for us because it means that we can ignore the spectral components with small eigenvalues for $P^k$ with large $k$.

But I don't know if there is a similar decomposition for non-self-adjoint operators. I knew that we can always use the SVD to get $Pu=\sum_i \lambda_i <\psi_i,u>\phi_i$, but we cannot get the result like $P^ku=\sum_i \lambda_i^k <\psi_i,u>\phi_i$. I only knew some results on the the self-adjoint/normal operators or finite-dimensional matrices. Is there any result related to general non-self-adjoint operators?

Comment: What you say about self-adjoint operators is not true. A self-adjoint bounded linear operator on a Hilbert space need not have any eigenvectors (for example let $H=L^2([0,1])$ and $Pf(t)=tf(t)$.) There _is_ a Spectral Theorem here but it's not quite that simple. The _correct_ version of the spectral theorem extends to normal operators.

Comment: Thank David for the comment. Yes extra assumptions are required for such a decomposition. My question is, in which case we can perform such a decomposition for a NON-self-adjoint operator?

Comment: As I said, the spectral theorem works for normal operators as well.

Comment: Thank David. So how about non-normal operators? Is there any general result?

Comment: If there's a decomposition as above where the eigenfunctions are orthogonal it follows that the operator is normal.

Comment: Wow, it is interesting to know this conclusion. Do you think the decomposition is possible with non-orthogonal eigenfunctions? For example, a finite dimensional matrix always has an eigendecomposition.

Comment: No, a finite dimensional matrix does _not_ always have an eigendecomposition! Gotta go to work now...

Comment: OK. A finite matrix can be diagonalized only if it is diagonalizable. But this condition is very weaker than the matrix is normal. So can we get a weaker condition for general operators?

Comment: Yes, if you insist. An operator is diagonalizable when it is diagonalizable, just as for matrices.

Comment: I am very doubtful of the existence of a singular-value decomposition in general. I think you need to restrict to compact operators for that. For compact operators, one can do a Jordan decomposition, which might be useful for your purposes.